# Can I get a UV-irrelevant grid material on blender?

Tags: materials

I've been modelling on blender for a long time, and I was never really particular about what my default material is. Now, I've tried probuilder (unity plugin) and the only thing that I really enjoy and miss elsewhere is its default material that displays a grid. [image]

Is it possible to get such a material in blender? This material always displays in 1:1 and never stretches, essentially ignoring UV. If you scale or modify the mesh, the texture is always gonna show the grid as is.

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the blender Reddit made an custom node that does something like this.

[image]

He publiced it on blenderswap:
https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/85263

You can tweak it a bit, here is a node setup you can use:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty close to what I want. It's a bit too complicated, but obviously if it gets it done it's good enough. Meanwhile I made an experiment (being a beginner in cycles) and it worked also pretty close, except for a small problem. I made a 512 texture and applied it using box mapping on generated coordinates. It works pretty well too, but 3 of the planes are reversed. If I could solve this I'd have a very useful tool in my hands.

Comment: You might want to look in to the `multiedit` plugin, I believe it has the functionality to set origin points of vertex groups what should solve your rotation problem.